# Rotating Hub Tile in windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

Can any one throw idea on to develop Rotating Hub tile in Windows phone 8. Im pretty new to windows phone 8. Please give some idea  on this development.

Comment: What do you mean by _Rotating Hub Tile_ ?

Comment: Hub Tile Control should Animate to Rotate on 180 degree wrt to X AXIS